# String.Join is not working with AppendAllText (C#)

Tags: c#, string, join, stream, append

I have below string

```
string str= "Insert into " + tname + "(id, t, v) values(" + lc+ ", " + mc+ ", " + rc+");" + Environment.NewLine;
```

and I'm write it to file:

```
File.AppendAllText(fileName, str);
```

It's working.

I also tried to use  **string.Join**:

```
string str = string.Join("Insert into " + tname+ "(id, t, v) values(" + lc+ ", " + mc+ ", " + rc+ ");", Environment.NewLine);
File.AppendAllText(fileName, str);
```

but the file always is empty. What is wrong?

Comment: A good start is reading the [documentation on String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Join is to concatenate a String array with a separator..

Comment: 1) the order of the input parameters is wrong 2) the second parameter is supposed to be a `IEnumerable`. So even if you change the order you will get each character printed on a separate line

Comment: Here you use your long string as sperator for every char in a `Environment.NewLine` string so your file should contains only a `Environment.NewLine`...

Comment: Side note - this insert statement indicates you have different tables with the same structure, describing the same entities in your database. This is a bad database design. You should change that to a single table, and use whatever your current design table name means as another column in that table.

Comment: take `" "` (space) as the separator, then put it as first parameter, then replace all `+` with a `,` in your concatenated string., Because there is an [overload of String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes a `params string [ ]` as parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think what you need is string.Format()

```
string str = string.Format("Insert into {0}(id, t, v) values({1}, {2}, {3});{4}",tname, lc,mc,rc, Environment.NewLine);
```

[String.Format() documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`string.Join` is to concatenate a `String[]` of objects using a separator

eg

```
List<int> l= new List  { 1,2,3 };
var s = string.Join(",",l);
```

s is then `"1,2,3"`

In your code you are basically passing in a very long separator (your string) and an empty array.

[Documentation for string.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx)